# For loop returns only last value - dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop

I have a dataframe called LCI. In this dataframe, the index corresponds to a year+1. So index 0 is year 1 and so on. Some years contain values. I made a list of which years contain values. The list looks for like this [1,5,10,15,...,60]

| years | year_reality | CO2 | CH4 | NO2 | CO |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021 | 7.016 | 6.180 | 1.222 |  |
| 2 | 2022 | 2 | 0 | 0 |  |
| 3 | 2023 | 0 | 0 | 0 |  |

What I now want to do, is multiply the corresponding value of a year to another column of values called DynCFs. DynCFs looks like this

| years | year_reality | CO2 | CH4 | NO2 | CO |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021 | 3 | 6 | 2 |  |
| 2 | 2022 | 4 | 2 | 7 |  |
| 3 | 2023 | 3 | 7 | 6 |  |

so for example: LCI.loc[(0),'CO2']*DynCFs['CO2'] = [3*7.016
4*7.016*
37.016]
and call this new dataframe/column tempDLCA. (different name for each new column)

I want to make a new dataframe which is equal to the sum of the columns of tempDLCA, but only the values of the same years should be added up.

so for example:

| year_reality | CO2 |
| --- | --- |
| 2021 | 7.016*3 |
| 2022 | 7.016*4 |
| 2023 | 7.016*3 |

and

| year_reality | CO2 |
| --- | --- |
| 2022 | 2*3 |
| 2023 | 2*4 |
| 2024 | 2*3 |

should give this (what I will call dynLCA in the code)

| year_reality | CO2 |
| --- | --- |
| 2021 | 7.016*3 |
| 2022 | 7.016x4 + 2x3 |
| 2023 | 7.016x3+2x4 |
| 2024 | 2*3 |

ps.: i used x because * was not recognised by stackoverflow for some reason

I tried the following, but the output is only for the last i of listedValues(), so 60.

```
for i in listedValues:
    tempDLCA= pd.DataFrame()
    tempDLCA['Year_reality']= np.arange(2021+(i-1),4021+(i-1),1)
    tempDLCA['CO2'] = LCI.loc[(i-1),'CO2']*DynCFs['CO2']
    tempDLCA['CO'] = LCI.loc[(i-1),'CO']*DynCFs['CO'] 
    tempDLCA['NO2'] = LCI.loc[(i-1),'NO2']*DynCFs['NO2']
    tempDLCA['CH4'] = LCI.loc[(i-1),'CH4']*DynCFs['CH4']
    dynLCA= pd.concat([DLCA,tempDLCA], ignore_index=True).groupby(['Year_reality'], as_index = False).sum()
dynLCA
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: You are overwriting `dynLCA` in each iteration. If you want all the results you need to aggregate them in some collection, for example a list.

Comment: @matszwecja can you give me an example of how to do that? I just started learning python so I still need to learn a lot!

Comment: Before loop add `list_dynLCA = []` and replace `dynLCA = pd.concat...` with `list_dynLCA.append(pd.concat...)`

Comment: Can you include your expected output for your sample input? It is unclear what exactly you're trying to accomplish. Why are you multiplying 4 (the 2022 CH4 value) with 7.016 (the 2021 CO2 value)?

Comment: @matszwecja Thank you for the quick response. If I use the code you wrote, I do get a list. How do I convert this multidimensional list to the dataframe I want?

Comment: @not_speshal It seems like something went wrong there while uploading the question! I fixed it

Comment: Can you explain what exactly you're trying to do? Why are you multiplying each year's value in the first dataframe (`LCI`) with ALL the values in the second dataframe?

Comment: @not_speshal what you are asking is exactly what I am trying to do. I am not sure why you need more explaination.
focusing on CO2: LCI dataframe contains emissions in kg of CO2 at a certain year. DCF is how long the CO2 is in the atmosphere. So I need to know how much kg is left in the atmosphere of a certain year. That is why I am multiplying it all. If an emission is emitted in year 1, as is the case in the first table of the example, then it is easy to multiply. But if CO2 is emitted in year 2, i want to multiply it again with the first value of DCF in that year. Does this help you?